# Python UDP Server/Client

Tags: python, server, udp, client

I am trying to create a simple UDP server and client that will just exchange string acknowledgements of their connection. However, my client program does not carry out the data transfers though it seems to connect.

Here is the code for my server, I'm fairly certain this code is okay as I was able to have someone else connect their UDP client and the execution was fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

################ UDP SERVER ################################

import socket
import threading
import sys


ip = sys.argv[1] # this is local host
port = int(sys.argv[2])    # we'll start here.

sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

done = False
while not done:
   try:                                       # servers must bind an ip address and a port to work
     sock.bind((ip, port))
     done = True
     print("Listening on Port: " + str(port))
   except:
     print("Cannot connect to Port: " + str(port))
     port += 1 

def handel( a_socket):
  request = a_socket.recv(1024)
  print(str(request))
  a_socket.send("Thank you sir!")              # the acknowledgement 
  a_socket.close()                             # close the socket so it is NOT locked up.

while True:  
  message,addr = sock.recvfrom(2500) # OK someone pinged me.
  print( "received from "+str(addr)+': '+str(message) )
  sock.sendto("Thank you!",addr)
  sock.close()
  sys.exit()
  break
```

And here is my buggy UDP client program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

##################### UDP CLIENT #############################

import socket
import ssl
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
   print "USAGE program IP port "
   sys.exit()

try:
  ip = sys.argv[1]
  port = int(sys.argv[2])
except:
   print "USAGE program IP port "
   sys.exit()

def listen(ip, port):
  sox = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  try:
    sox.connect((ip, port))
    print("UDP server listening on Port: " +str(port))
    data, addr = sox.recvfrom(1024)
    print("Received: ", data, addr)
    sox.sendto("Thank you!", addr)
    sox.close()
  except:
    print("UDP server not listening on Port: " + str(port))
    sys.exit()

listen(ip, port)
```

Written in Python 2.7, takes two command line inputs for ip address and port number. Let me know what you think, thanks for your time!

Comment: Your server waits to receive a datagram and then sends a response.  Your client also waits to receive a datagram and then sends a response.  Since they're both waiting for the other one to speak, it's not surprising that they don't make much progress.  But +1 for a nicely-composed question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few tweaks for a working client and server. The client does not need to call connect() on the socket and it should call sendto() before calling recvfrom(). It is a good idea to add a timeout to the client.

Note if you want to bind to all available IPv4 addresses, specify 0.0.0.0 or "" as your IP address on the server.

**server.py**

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

################ UDP SERVER ################################

import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("USAGE: server.py IP port")
    sys.exit()

ip = sys.argv[1]           # this is local host
port = int(sys.argv[2])    # start port here

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    try:
        # server must bind to an ip address and port
        sock.bind((ip, port))
        print("Listening on Port:", port)
        break
    except Exception:
        print("ERROR: Cannot connect to Port:", port)
        port += 1

try:
    while True:
        message, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)  # OK someone pinged me.
        print(f"received from {addr}: {message}")
        sock.sendto(b"Thank you!", addr)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    sock.close()
```

**client.py**

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

##################### UDP CLIENT #############################

import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("USAGE: client.py IP port")
    sys.exit()

try:
    ip = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])
except Exception:
    print("USAGE: client.py IP port")
    sys.exit()

def listen(ip, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        print("UDP sending on Port:", port)
        sock.settimeout(5)
        sock.sendto("Hello".encode(), (ip, port))
        print("message sent")
        print("waiting for response on socket")
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print("Received:", data.decode(), addr)
    except socket.timeout:
        print("ERROR: acknowledgement was not received")
    except Exception as ex:
        print("ERROR:", ex)
    finally:
        sock.close()

listen(ip, port)
```

**Output for server**

```
> python server5.py localhost 8000
Listening on Port: 8000
received from ('127.0.0.1', 54773): b'Hello'
```

**Output for client**

```
> python client5.py localhost 8000
UDP sending on Port: 8000
message sent
waiting for response on socket
Received: Thank you! ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
```